# Jquery animate - callback executing before animation is complete

Tags: javascript, jquery

What I'd like to accomplish is for the element to expand in height, and then apply a background image once the height change is complete. I've noticed that the background image in the callback applies before the height animation is complete resulting in laggy performance. Can anyone tell me why this is?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#hero').animate({
        height: ($(window).height() - $("#hero").offset().top - 50) 
    }, 100, function() {
        $('#hero').css('background-image', 'url(./img/hero.jpg)');
    });
});
```

Comment: Well, it shouldn't. Are you sure that it is not related to the very short time (100ms)? The documentation cleary says that the callback function (identified as _complete_ anyway), is  **"A function to call once the animation is complete."** . Also, as a side note, 100ms are quite fast for such an animation, you may find yourself wondering if the background change is happening before of after, so you should try to increase that time.

Comment: Works fine for me http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/nmqot5a8/

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I thought so too. It's strange, I set the animation to 2000 and it seems to wait 2 seconds, then perform the height change with the background already set. It's like the 2000ms is acting as a delay instead of the animation time.

Edit: On firefox it does not do this, the animation begins immediately and takes 2s. However the background is still changed halfway through before the height change completes.

Comment: @JamesMyers: What jQuery version are you using? j08691's fiddle works just beautifully.

Comment: You see the example I posted right? And that it works fine? Can you recreate your issue in a fiddle?

Comment: I'm wondering if his laggy performance may be related to its browser rather than jQuery itself... The only alternative you have to the callback in any case is using the .one jQuery prototype to detect the div's animation end, but it's pointless in my opinion. If there is any problem it has to be somewhere else

Comment: Looks like the animation is working in the fiddle j08691 provided. I put my project up at http://dev.jamesmyers.me

Comment: It works perfectly to me, not sure what the problem is! :P In any case, you have a js Syntax error : `$(...).velocity is not a function` you should solve that first! It is at line 11 on tricky.js

Comment: Sorry about the syntax error, I was trying velocity as a drop in replacement for jQuery since it apparently performs better and forgot to change that back. Which browser are you using?

It seems to work well in Firefox for me on OS X, but not Chrome or Opera(based on Chromium).

Comment: @JamesMyers : I tried it in Chrome and Firefox, in any case Robert McKee below found an incongruence about a css animation. Despite it works perfectly here (not sure why at this point) you should definetly take a look at his answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a `transition: all 1s ease` on `#hero`, which will cause the animation to play erratically since you are trying to use css3 animations to animate the jQuery animation (and throw all kinds of timing problems).

What I suspect is happening is that you are getting notified that the jQuery animation completed, but the css3 animation doesn't complete for an additional 1s, which is why you are seeing what you are.